# Full screen Pop-up on Pure Javascript - No Framework

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I need to write a javascript function like a;

While my application runs on browser I will refresh the page and it will open a pop-up, close the old page and pop-up will be displayed in full screen. How can I do this? I did try this code below.

```js
var elem = document.documentElement;
function fullScreen() {
  //  var ofisWin = window.open("ofis.html");
  if (document.fullscreenElement !== null) {
    console.log("fselement: " + document.fullscreenElement);
  } else {
    openFullscreen();
    window.close();
  }
}

function openFullscreen() {
  var ofisWin = window.open("ofis.html", "ofis", "fullScreen");
  if (ofisWin == null) {
    console.log('The popup was blocked!');
  }
  console.log(window.document.fullscreenElement);
  console.log("fullscreen request!");
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem = window.top.document.body; //To break out of frame in IE
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

fullScreen()
```

Comment: You luckily cannot do that from a normal browser page. You can perhaps investigate "kiosk mode" for your preferred browser

Comment: Also `elem` is a `var` in another function so is not available in the openFullScreen - I changed your code to not give errors

Comment: Thank you for your all help! You are great person